# update x-for from Ajax - Alpine Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, alpine.js

How can I tell Alpine to update the `x-for` from the server. In another word, How to do force update in AlpineJs.

```html
<select id="branches" name="branches" x-data="ajax" >
    <option value="" disabled selected="">Choose</option>
    <template x-for="branche in branches">
        <option :value="branche.ID" x-text="branche.Branch_name"></option>
    </template>
</select>
```

```js
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.data('ajax', () => ({
            async branches() {
                return await $.post("path-url", {
                    tb: "branches"
                }, (data) => {
                    return data;
                });
            }
        }))
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$.post` is from [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):

```
<select id="branches" name="branches" x-data="getBranches()">
  <option value="" disabled selected="">Choose</option>
  <template x-for="branch in branches">
    <option :value="branch.ID" x-text="branch.Branch_name"></option>
  </template>
</select>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('getBranches', () => ({
    branches: [],

    init() {
      $.post("path-url", {
        tb: "branches"
      }, (data) => {
        this.branches = data
      })
    }
  }))
})
</script>
```

We used the [`init()` method](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data#init-functions) to get the data, that executes before rendering the component. You don't have to "force" the update, just mutate a reactive Alpine.js data variable and Alpine.js will update the DOM shortly after.

Comment: Your update code is helpful but I am sorry I do not understand "just mutate a reactive Alpine.js data variable" meaning of it, Can you give me an example? or explain more?

Comment: Sure! So here `branches` is a *reactive* [Alpine.js data variable](https://alpinejs.dev/start-here#declaring-data). It means that Alpine.js detects when its value has changed and updates the frontend DOM where necessary (e.g. where this variable is printed so the new value must be shown). Mutating the data is just a "fancy" way to say updating its value. In this example after the `$.post()` request at `this.branches = data` line we are mutating a reactive data. So after that Alpine.js will automatically update the frontend DOM.